# Add Gif animation to checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have found nice code, that stylize checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<label id="checkbox_lab" for="checkbox" class="checkbox_lab"></label>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox_lab {
    background: url("images/off.png") no-repeat;
    height: 28px;
    width: 81px;
    display: block;
}
.checkbox_lab_sel {
    background: url("images/on.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Javascript (uses jquery):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".checkbox").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).next("label").addClass("checkbox_lab_sel");
            }else{
                $(this).next("label").removeClass("checkbox_lab_sel");
            }
        });
    });
```

It is working really nice. I would like "nice toggle animation from on to off and vice versa", which is saved in animated gif, but... I'm not very good in JS and don't know how to do it. Does anybody have got idea?

Comment: Sounds like a mildly crazy idea but surely you just want to have the exact same code that you have there but with animated gifs showing the animations that you would like instead of the two PNG images? Won't work well when the page loads for the first time though as that would show an animation too which may look a bit weird.

Comment: Well this is solution for stylizing checkboxes I have found in the net, but I do not insist on this solution. I am open to better way to stylize checkboxes (and animate background ^^).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have a quick [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cLb5F/)

HTML

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
<label id="checkbox_lab" for="checkbox" class="checkbox_lab"></label>​
```

CSS

```
.checkbox {
    /*display: none;*/
}
.checkbox_lab {
    background: url("images/off.png") no-repeat;
    height: 28px;
    width: 81px;
    display: block;
}
.checkbox_lab_sel {
    background-image: url('http://cdn.rpxnow.com/rel/img/9a8269421303631316be4ab5e34870e1.gif');
}​
```

Javascript

```
$(".checkbox").change(function(){
    $('#checkbox_lab').toggleClass('checkbox_lab_sel');
        });​
```

Hope this helps!